# How to express relationship between two/multi dimensional array & the pointer expressions

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
       int a[2][2][2]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
       printf("%d\t%d",*(*(*(a+1)+1)+1),a[1][1][1]);
}
```

The output of the code is 8 8 but the expression `*(*(*(a+i)+j)+k);` & `a[i][j][k];` are equal I know how to evolve the expression `a[i][j][k];` but I don't have an idea how to evolve the expression `*(*(*(a+i)+j)+k);` with proper priority operations of `*` operator & `()` operator. Please explain it with taking some values of `i,j,k`.

Answer (score 0):

In pointer arithmetic,
`array[i]` = `*(array + i)`.
`array[i][j]` = `*(*(array + i) + j)`.
`array[i][j][k]` = `*(*(*(array + i) + j) + k)`

Comment: *(array+i)= *(array[0][0][0]+1) =*(some address+1)=*(address) then we take the value at the address then how to proceed the next iteration

Answer (score 0):

Initially, `a` is pointing towards `1`. When you do `a+1` it moves to the `5`, and when you dereference (*) you cause the next `+1` to make it move only 2 positions, to the `7`. The second * causes the third `+1` to move it to the last element, `8`, and the final * actually gets the value from that address (which is 8).